# Setting Global Query Filter ef core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Brief: I'm facing a problem with setting Global Query Filter using Claim added to signed user.
Error scenario: when signing in ef core is still not loaded so `OnModelCreating` function is triggered that contains the configuration of my entities where I set Global Query Filter using tenant id claim using this function

```
    private long GetRequestTenantId()
    {
        try
        {
            var tenantClaim = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "TenantId").FirstOrDefault();

            if (tenantClaim == null)
                return 0;
            
            bool IsParsed = long.TryParse(tenantClaim.Value, out long tenantId);

            if (!IsParsed)
                return 0;

            return tenantId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

which naturally return `0` on first run.
Is there any other way to set Global Query Filter to fix this problem?
What I tried to do was set query filter according to the user that sent the request.
which works fine when I relaunch the application and happens again when the session ends and I log in again.
Edit: My query filter is TenantId.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track, but I don't fully understand what you're asking for.  How would you like to fix the problem?  For cases when `GetRequestTenantId()` returns 0, do you want your DbContext to behave as if there is no query filter?

Comment: Do you want to ignore the global query filter if ``tenantId`` is 0? and share your ``OnModelCreating `` method as well.

Comment: Where is your filter?

Comment: The problem is when I trigger Login action (which allow Anonymous) to authorize the user, The request sent doesn't contain tenantId, So GetRequestTenantId returns zero that makes query filter on TenantId == 0 and this prevents the user from getting any data

Comment: @MazenBahy People were asking what is your filter expression - apparently it couldn't be TenatantId as you wrote, but something like `HasFilter(e => e.TenantId == GetRequestTenantId())`. If that's true, then you simply modify the expression to treat 0 differently, e.g. `e => GetRequestTenantId() == 0 || e.TenantId == GetRequestTenantId()`